# Avoiding mass assignment MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am a beginner programmer and faced a problem, how to avoid mass assignment, for now i got only two very small Entities Author and Book.

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        Authors = new List<Author>();
    }
    public int? BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

And I wanted to avoid assignment (bookInDb.Title = book.Title) when I am updating a book:

```
public void UpdateBook(Book book)
    {
        var bookInDb = GetBook(book.BookId.Value);

        bookInDb.Title = book.Title; // I want this logic to be replaced in more elegent way

        var authorsInDb = bookInDb.Authors.Select(f => f.AuthorId).ToList();

        var editedAuthors = book.Authors.Select(f => f.AuthorId).ToList();
        var authorToAdd = GetAuthorsToAdd(authorsInDb, editedAuthors);

        authorToAdd.ToList().ForEach(x=>bookInDb.Authors.Add(x));

        var authorsIdToRemove = authorsInDb.Except(editedAuthors);
        var authorsToRemove = AuthorsToRemove(bookInDb.Authors, authorsIdToRemove);

        authorsToRemove.ToList().ForEach(x => bookInDb.Authors.Remove(x));

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

For now It is not a problem, but if I would have more fields, am I supposed to that in this way or there is much easier way ? 
Thanks for Your answers.

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateBook([Bind(Exclude = "Title")] Book book)`

More info and more approaches [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing this issue in C# .net core API, then add [Bind] or [Bind("prop1","prop2")] instead of [FromBody] in the controller.

ref - https://softdevpractice.com/blog/asp-net-core-how-to-prevent-mass-assignment-attacks/